# Report showing raw data instead of data from linq query?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, crystal-reports

My report keeps showing what I believe is raw data in the report for the name from the employees field. The sql tables have the correct data but the report never has the correct name. It always shows the employee with a pk of zero instead of the employee from the join. I think I am showing the correct data from the `expenseHdr`s and `expenseDtl`s fields because it looks right in the report but when I hover over query when debugging all I see is the expense details (line items in my report)but I am newer to visual studio.

Basically it seems like there is a disconnect between my query and my datasource or there is something wrong with my join. Here is the sql select I got from the datasource and below is the query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT expenseHdr.rptNo,expenseHdr.description,expenseHdr.purpose,
expenseHdr.reimbursement, expenseHdr.department, expenseHdr.period, 
expenseDtl.expDesc, expenseDtl.expType, expenseDtl.expCost, 
expenseDtl.expDate, employees.name, expenseDtl.expNo,   
expenseDtl.location
FROM   (Intranet.dbo.expenseHdr expenseHdr INNER JOIN
Intranet.dbo.expenseDtl expenseDtl ON 
expenseHdr.rptNo=expenseDtl.rptNo) INNER JOIN Intranet.dbo.employees 
employees ON expenseHdr.empPk=employees.pk
ORDER BY expenseDtl.expNo
```

```cs
private void launchReport(int pKReport)
{
    using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var query = (from s in db.expenseHdrs
                         join d in db.expenseDtls on s.rptNo equals d.rptNo
                         where s.rptNo == pKReport
                         join g in db.employees on s.empPk equals g.pk
                         select new
                         {
                             s.period,
                             s.description,
                             s.department,
                             s.rptNo,
                             s.reimbursement,
                             s.purpose,
                             g.name,
                             d.expDate,
                             d.expType,
                             d.expDesc
                     });

        expenseReportMain cr1 = new expenseReportMain();

        cr1.FileName = @"\\SRV-NAS\Intranet\Reports\expenseReportMain.rpt";

        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        connectionInfo.ServerName = "svr-sql";
        connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "intranet";
        connectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
        connectionInfo.Password = "******";

        SetDBLogonForReport(connectionInfo, cr1);
        cr1.SetDataSource(query);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;
    }
}

private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo,
                                 expenseReportMain reportDocument)
{
    Tables tables = reportDocument.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
        tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
    }
}
```

Also I edited in some sample data per request:

```
expenseHdr             expenseDtl                employees

rptNo  empPk           expNo   rptNo             pK    name    userid
1      333             3       1                 333   Tom     tom.b
2      240             4       1                 240   Kelly   kelly.c
3      542             5       2                 542   Jean    jean.g
                       6       3
```

So any info off the employees table will not show correctly on the report. The data from the other two tables displays fine.

Comment: I have confirmed that there is no issue with the query and the problem is still unknown. Every time I try to display a field on the report from the employees table it only grabs the first record in the table. Ignores that part of the query.

Comment: Is the SQL query what you want? And the LINQ what you have? You do not have a WHERE clause in the SQL query, where as there is a WHERE clause in the LINQ. Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: I believe the SQL query is auto generated by crystal just so I have the data available to access. The linq query is what is looking for the specific data which is i believe is correct.

Comment: Still at a loss on this if anyone could please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because in your linq treatment you don't have just join operator, but you have select many.

You sql query : you have query with three join

You linq query : you have select many, with two select , and for each select you have an join

so it's normal that It always shows the employee with a pk of zero instead of the employee from the join, because you don't have join on employe with expenseHdrs.

```
 var query = (from s in db.expenseHdrs
                     join d in db.expenseDtls on s.rptNo equals d.rptNo
                     where s.rptNo == pKReport
                     join g in db.employeess on g.pk equals s.empPk
                     select new
                     {
                        //Adjust your select

                     });
```

Comment: isnt this that join? from g in db.employees
                         join r in db.expenseHdrs on g.pk equals r.empPk

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: (from a in A 
         where A.condition == ..
         join b in B on 
         on A.id equals B.id
         join c in C
         on C.id equals B.id
         ....

Comment: from s in db.expenseHdrs
                             join d in db.expenseDtls on s.rptNo equals d.rptNo
                             join g in db.employees on s.empPk equals g.pk
                             where s.rptNo == pKReport

Comment: Also tried adding this to where clase "&& g.pk == s.empPk"   same result

Comment: Almost: `g.pk equals d.empPk` should be `s.empPk equals g.pk`.

Comment: var query = (from s in db.expenseHdrs
                     join d in db.expenseDtls on s.rptNo equals d.rptNo
                     where s.rptNo == pKReport
                     join g in db.employees on s.empPk equals g.pk

Comment: yes I see and thats what i did. I adjusted it with gerts. Same result. name with 0 pk instead of correct name

Answer (score 0):

what I remember changing your query by placing where after both joins as earlier definition might effect:

```
var query = (from s in db.expenseHdrs
                         join d in db.expenseDtls on s.rptNo equals d.rptNo
                         where s.rptNo == pKReport
                         join g in db.employees on s.empPk equals g.pk
                         select new
                         {
                             s.period,
                             s.description,
                             s.department,
                             s.rptNo,
                             s.reimbursement,
                             s.purpose,
                             g.name,
                             d.expDate,
                             d.expType,
                             d.expDesc
                     });
```

To:

```
var query = (from s in db.expenseHdrs
                         join d in db.expenseDtls on s.rptNo equals d.rptNo
                         join g in db.employees on s.empPk equals g.pk
                         where s.rptNo == pKReport
                         select new
                         {
                             s.period,
                             s.description,
                             s.department,
                             s.rptNo,
                             s.reimbursement,
                             s.purpose,
                             g.name,
                             d.expDate,
                             d.expType,
                             d.expDesc
                     });
```

Will solve your issue because in sql you need to join all tables before where clause.

Comment: Sorry I have busy the past couple weeks relocating across the USA. I tried this and it does not make any difference. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your table ddl and sample data?

Comment: I edited in some sample data to the original post. Let me know if there is anything else I can provide you. I really appreciate the help

Comment: As your data suggest rptNo in expenseHdr is primary key so correspond to single employee id So as this is your base table and you have filter of rptNO. Now the result will be single rptNo and Single employee and may have multiple expanses but employee remain same. this suggest your report behaviour is normal.

Comment: So you think my report is correct based on my current join? I am not sure I follow.

Comment: if rptNo in expenseHdr is primary key or unique then there should be only single employee name in result as your query suggest. So behaviour is normal. Now the question is what actually you want.

Comment: Yes the response is normal behaviour if you have rptNo in expenseHdr as unique.

Comment: I want the correct employee to show in the report that filled out the expense information and is why I am storing the empPk in the expense Hdr

Comment: you mean if you select pKReport = 1

then 

rptNo expNo emp_name
1  3  Tom
1  4  Tom

if pKReport = 2

rptNo expNo emp_name
2  5  Kelly

if pKReport = 3

rptNo expNo emp_name
3  6  Jean

Comment: Correct and every where I am doing this in my application it is working fine. It is only with the crystal report that I am having issues

Comment: you mean in every case either it is pkReport 1 or 2 you get only employee name Tom in each case. and data output by my post is actually needed

Comment: if yes then it seems to be crystal report issue as query seems to be fine with required output. if you are ok and provide remote access then I can provide you assistance by checking your project.

Comment: Yes that would be very appreciated! I will be available 7 PM Central Std time and later. If that does not work please let me know when you would like me to be available. Thank You!

Comment: sharafjaffri, I am available any time. My email is in my profile. Thanks

Comment: sorry for late reply actually I was ill with temp 103-104 since last few days just today got little better. let me contact you tonight or tommarow

Comment: No problem! Hopefully you are better. I look forward to it!

Comment: I will be available today after 9, GMT+5 and sunday you can connect me at skype sharafjaffri88